# Why is glGetUniformLocation failing me?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-3

I found Gwen a few days ago and thought it looked like the perfect GUI toolkit for my project.  But oh, dear, look at all that OpenGL 2 code in the renderer.  So I thought I'd write an OpenGL 3 renderer so I can actually use it, but I'm a lot more familiar with CG than GLSL and I've gotten myself stuck writing up the sample.  I think if I can just get these uniform variables set, it should be basically done.

The shaders compile and link without a problem.  I narrowed it down to glGetUniformLocation returning -1 for the orthographic matrix and the texture sampler, but I don't know why exactly it's doing that.  The typical problem seems to be that if you aren't actually using them, they get optimized out, but I've used them both.

If anybody has any ideas, I'm all ears.  Will be more than happy to post/link the full thing once it works properly.  This is my first stab at GLSL, so I could easily be doing something dumb.  I did just get finished setting up CG for another project, so I'm not *completely* clueless.

Shader Init code called after setting up the OpenGL context:

```
void InitializeShaders(void)
{
    g_ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    g_VertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    g_FragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(g_VertexShader, 1, (const GLchar **)&VertexShaderData, 0);
    glShaderSource(g_FragmentShader, 1, (const GLchar **)&FragmentShaderData, 0);

    glCompileShader(g_VertexShader);
    CheckShaderCompile(g_VertexShader);

    glCompileShader(g_FragmentShader);
    CheckShaderCompile(g_FragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(g_ShaderProgram, g_VertexShader);
    glAttachShader(g_ShaderProgram, g_FragmentShader);

    glBindAttribLocation(g_ShaderProgram, 0, "position");
    glBindAttribLocation(g_ShaderProgram, 1, "color");
    glBindAttribLocation(g_ShaderProgram, 2, "texCoord");

    glBindFragDataLocation(g_ShaderProgram, 0, "color");

    glLinkProgram(g_ShaderProgram);
    CheckShaderLink();

    g_OrthoTransformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(g_ShaderProgram, "orthoTransform");
    g_TextureLocation = glGetUniformLocation(g_ShaderProgram, "textureSampler");
}
```

The shaders are stored as a string in a header file, but I stripped out all the newlines and backslashes so they aren't so painful to look at.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330

in vec4 position;
out vec4 outPosition;
uniform mat4x4 orthoTransform;
void main(void)
{
    outPosition = position * orthoTransform;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 texCoord;
in vec4 color;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
void main(void)
{
    //outColor = texture(textureSampler, texCoord) * color;
    outColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Also, unless `orthoTransform` is a transposed matrix (or row-major if you like), you should right-multiply `position`, not on the left as you currently do it. And if you did transpose it, then set the transpose flag correctly on your `glUniformMatrix` call and right-multiply it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is really simple: your vertex shader does nothing, so OpenGL is optimizing it out.

In order to render a triangle, OpenGL needs a clip-space position for each of the triangle's vertices. It is the job of the vertex shader to provide this. Because OpenGL cannot tell what vertex shader output you intend to be the clip-space position, OpenGL requires that you write to `gl_Position` as the output. It is legal to avoid this, which is why your shader compiles and links. But as you found, rendering fails.

Comment: Gah, I even had `gl_Position` in there at one point, but I guess I was still mucking around with other stuff and never tried running it before I changed it.  I think I read something about all the other built in gl_* variables being deprecated in 3.3 and assumed `gl_Position` was too.  Really wish there was more up to date info around to look at.

Comment: @Apostate: There is plenty of info on OpenGL. The [GLSL specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/) for example is quite readable. And the OpenGL Wiki [page on GLSL is pretty comprehensive](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `glBindFragDatalocation` should bind `outColor` and not `color` in this case. Second, what you give the shader program are **vertex** attributes and not fragment attributes. The `out`s of the vertex shader should match the `in`s of the fragment shader.

The reason why the location of `textureSampler` is -1 is because you have commented out the code.
The reason why the location of `orthoTransform` is -1 is because it is actually never used and optimized out. The `out` `outPosition` is never used by the fragment shader which in turn causes it the `orthoTransform` uniform to be optimized out.

I think what you are looking for is `gl_Position`.

Comment: Whoops, I had color as an `inout` at one point and forgot to change glBindFragDataLocation back when I changed it to seperate variables.  Also, I knew textureSampler wouldn't work the way it was in what I posted, I probably should have changed that to avoid confusion.  Was hoping it would be implied that I was trying to just get some color on the screen for testing, but normally I'm trying to read from the texture.